# Terraform - Creating a Data-Only Module which has outputs which need for_each to be set

Tags: terraform, azure-rm

For a project I am working on we currently have a lot of duplicate networking data which could use refactoring. I want to move all the subnets data to a seperate [data-only module](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/composition#data-only-modules) which can be used for all [DTAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development,_testing,_acceptance_and_production) envs. This would cut out a lot of duplicate code. The problem is that I have a for_each set on the module call, which causes issues. The data I want to move to the subnet has each.value in the code, which I cannot reference anymore.

Here is an example of the Data output, with a each.value.

```
output "subnets" {
  value = [
    {
      group         = "example-vnet"
      address_space = cidrsubnet(each.value, 22 - split("/", each.value)[1], 0)
      prefix        = "24"
      members = [subnet data]
```

Here is how it was originally referenced in the module it was used in.

```
module "spoke_network_prd" {
  for_each = local.region_spoke_network_prd

  source = "../modules/spoke_network_module"

  subnets = # The value of the output subnets, which could use the for_each.
```

How do I get the for_each to still work?

I tried to just paste the original code into a data module and reference it, which produces the exact same output, but the for_each is not valid anymore.

Comment: Modules are not well suited for data. Actual sources of data such as data, external data, or YAML/JSON files are better suited for data in Terraform.

Comment: @MatthewSchuchard, I'm having trouble guessing the reason you say: "Modules are not well suited for data." To me it looks like yet another possibility (in addition to the alternatives you listed) with its own strengths and weaknesses.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the templatefile function and passing the each value as a variable inside the config

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).